# Indentation problem after commit with Git

Tags: git, atom-editor, indentation, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm having a problem with git, and I'm not sure how to solve it. I made a commit, and the code was aligned correctly, one line under another. I used Source Tree to commit, but for some reason the code indented after it was staged. I checked the actual file and it wasn't indented, so I thought it was just a display problem. When I pushed the code, it is indented, and now it's been passed on to the repository. I want to reverse the indentation, but as the local file isn't indented, I can't change it. I've been using this method for a long time. I updated the Source Tree software after it happened, and it didn't happen on the next commit. What can I do to fix the indentation on this earlier commit?

[image: source tree][image: editor][image: git]

Here are the images. I also tried retyping all the code instead of copying and pasting it.

Update: I'm still getting this issue, and I'm starting to think that maybe the Atom text editor is the cause. I always tab the code across to align it, but if I hit enter to push it to a new line, Atom indents using spaces. I don't really care whether tabs or spaces are there, but I want to make sure it's correctly aligned when it's committed.

Comment: You can revert the commit and try again. `git revert HEAD~` to go back one commit.

Comment: Can we see how Source Tree and Git shows it, and how the file looks in your editor please? that would help understanding what happened.

Comment: I reverted it, but now when I add the code back in and try to recommit it, the indentation is still there

Comment: I added some images to show the differences

Comment: Do you use spaces or tabs for indentation? It might be mixed of the two, displayed in equal indents and actually in different widths.

Comment: You're right, I usually use tabs, but it is a mixture. I just checked it in Word. I've never had a problem with mixing them before. Thanks